# Cannot connect to Socket IO with Node, Express, and EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am not connecting to `Socket IO` in my node app and I believe it has something to do with my EJS configuration and how I am rendering `index.ejs` and `layout.ejs` files:

When I connect to `Socket IO` I want to console log that a user has been connected:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user is connected')

  socket.on('send-message', (data) => {
    io.sockets.emit('new-message', data)
  })
```

Here is how I handle the backend when I go to `localhost:3000` here is my code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
})
```

But when I go to `localhost:3000` it does not console that a user has been connect to `Socket IO`

I tried this as well:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.ejs', {root:__dirname})
})
```

and also

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(process.env.PWD+'/client/views/index.ejs')
})
```

but I still do not connect.

Any ideas what I need to do?

More Code:

**server/app.js**

```
const
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    ejsLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    ...
    ...

// environment port
const
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    mongoConnectionString = process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/context-app'

    mongoose.connect(mongoConnectionString, (err) => {
      console.log(err || "Connected to MongoDB (context-app)")
    })

// ejs configuration
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', process.env.PWD+'/client/views');
app.use(ejsLayouts)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
})

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user is connected');

  socket.on('send-message', (data) => {
    io.sockets.emit('new-message', data)
  })
})

server.listen(port, (err) => {
  console.log(err || 'listening on my very special port ' + port)
})
```

**client/views/layout.ejs**

```
<!-- /views/layout.ejs -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>React Intro</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script>...</script>
  <script>...</script>
  <script>
    var socket = io();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <% include partials/nav %>
    <div class="container">
        <%- body %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**client/views/index.ejs**

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script type="text/babel" src="../app.js"></script>
```

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

The problem was on the client side: I simply forgot to load the `Socket IO` script: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: Have you checked the console in your browser to see if there are any errors there? It's not clear from the source you posted if the client is loading the socket.io.js script.

Comment: that was the problem --- I forgot to load the following script :   <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: Glad you found the problem. I answered below in case this happens to someone else. If you could accept the answer it might help the next person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the you are loading the socket.io script on the client side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```